# Is it normal for Google Chome development channel to not have the 'Paste and Go' option in the address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

How I've installed
On Ubuntu 11.10 I've added the Google to my Software Sources, then used the following commands(not 100% accurate) sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable

I also get the same thing on Chromium which is installed via the Ubuntu Software Centre and also on Fedora 15 which i installed via the download on the Google chrome website.

On Windows 7 I have the 'Paste and Go', I was wondering if I could get the same on the linix OSs that I used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a "Paste & Go" option available at the bottom of the menu that seems to offer the same functionality. It says "Paste & Search" when the item in the clipboard is not a valid URL.

However, I have the google-chrome-stable version installed.

EDIT: I am running Ubuntu 11.04, not 11.10